# writing application master for Yarn Application

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am new to YARN, and I am developing a framework to launch java applications via YARN container. To register my ApplicationMaster to resource manager, the code is executing registerApplicationMaster("",0,"") which works fine on single node cluster. But the same call hangs forever in case of multi-node cluster. I am wondering if not passing these parameters properly is causing this. 
Even if it is not, I want to know what are these for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public abstract RegisterApplicationMasterResponse registerApplicationMaster(String appHostName, int appHostPort, String appTrackingUrl)`

- appHostName - Name of the host on which master is running
- appHostPort - Port master is listening on
- appTrackingUrl - URL at which the master info can be seen